# How To Install Latest Cyanogenmod From Clockworkmod Recovery - Galaxy Note GT-N7000 (Intl)

Tags: cyanogenmod, installation, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

**(Short Version)**

How to install Cyanogenmod from ClockWorkMod Recovery. What tools do I need as a first timer? (I already have ClockWorkMod Recovery installed)

**(Long Version)**

I tried to install Cyanogenmod with the [get.cm](http://get.cm) and [get.cm/app](http://get.cm/app) instructions. But the install process was interrupted by windows driver recognition.

All I have now is a ClockWorkMod Recovery and, apparently, nothing more. The Cyanogenmod Windows Installer recognize the device but can't continue from this point (it asks for enabling/allowing USB Debugging).

What tools do I need to copy Cyanogenmod in Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04 to my Galaxy Note GT-N7000 (Intl) with only ClockWorkMod Recovery and proceed with the install process?

Thanks in advance!

**(My devices)**

Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000 (Intl) - and a notebook with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 64 Professional

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed Cyanogenmod on a galaxy note 8.  What worked for me was to copy Cyanogenmod to an microSD card.  Then with microSD plugged into phone, boot the clockwork, and install from SD card.

Hope that Helps!!